# Mutually Exclusive code

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, mutual-exclusion

How can I tell is code is mutually exclusive in the critical section? I understand the concept but when it comes to code tracing I'm having a hard time identifying mutually exclusive code. Heres the code segment in question...

```
// flag[0] and [1] start as true

Thread 1
for(;;) {
    flag[1] = false;
    while(flag[2] == false) 
        flag[1] = true;
    flag[1] = false;
    // critical section
    flag[1] = true;
    // exit critical 
}

Thread 2
for(;;) {
    flag[2] = false;

    while(flag[1] == false);

    // critical section
    flag[2] = true;
    // exit critical 
}
```

This sucks so any general insight into mutual exclusion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having a hard time identifying mutually exclusive code

As a rule of thumb, when you are browsing code, you can spot mutually exclusive code (a.k.a critical sections) by thinking of these questions:

1. Have I got here publicly accessible data (Data is everything: instances of objects, std containers, etc...)?
2. Who can access it?
3. Can they access it while I'm accessing it?

If the answer to all these questions is **yes**, you probably have to take care and protect this data using some kind of synchronization mechanism.

For primitive types, the simplest way to go is probably atomic variables.

For more complicated types, e.g. container of some sort, you should probably use mutexes.

For more complicated scenarios, such as drivers, interrupts and more, you should read more about spinlocks and read-write-locks and more advanced mechanisms.

**Note:** This is a oversimplification of the issue, but I believe it paints a pretty good picture for someone who is starting to tackle this complicated issue.